# Knights , Knaves and Spies - Part 2

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

I was working my way through some Knight and Knave Puzzles in [Discrete Maths by Rosen](http://www.flipkart.com/discrete-mathematics-its-applications-combinatorics-graph-theory-english-7th/p/itmdwxxszhczjrnf), when I came across the following question:

> There are  inhabitants of an island on which there are three kinds of people:
>
> - Knights who always tell the truth
> - Knaves who always lie
> - Spies who can either lie or tell the truth.
>
> You encounter three people, A, B, and C.
>
> You know one of these people is a knight, one is a knave, and one is a spy.
>
> Each of the three people knows the type of person each of other two is.
>
> ***For this situation, if possible, determine whether there is a unique solution and determine who the knave, knight, and spy is :***
>
> ***A says “I am the knight,” B says “I am the knave,” and C says “B is the knight.”***

***Book Solution:***

> **$A\Rightarrow Knight$**
> **$B\Rightarrow Spy$**
> **$C\Rightarrow Knave$**

***Doubt:***

I am not able to understand why this is the case .

- For A it is fine
- For C it is fine
- But for B , if B is the Spy and B says "I am the knave" -- does that mean B is a Spy who lies ?

Comment: Does each Spy either *always* lie or *always* tell the truth (you just don't know which), or does he lie and tell the truth at random, like Jokers in other questions on this site?

Comment: Hi , @randal'thor , The Spies either always lie or tell the truth

Comment: How does that make them a different 'kind of person' then? A Spy must be either a Knight or a Knave (at least in terms of their truthfulness)?

Comment: Hi , @randal'thor , I kinda get what you are trying to say . But I think what Smullyan , meant is that the Truth Signal of a Spy , if such a thing exists , is not pre-decided to be set to True or False but rather depends on the situation . In that case , I think that they are equivalent to the jokers you mentioned . Otherwise , it beats me ...

Comment: @randal'thor: A knave always lies. Doesn't mean that a person who always lies must be a knave.

Comment: For future reference, could I possibly suggest not putting your entire answer in blockquotes? Thank you!

Comment: Sure , @Emrakul , I will keep this in mind :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If C is the knight, then by C's statement, B is the knight, contradiction. If B is the knight, then by B's statement, B is the knave, contradiction. So **A is the knight**.

If B is the knave, then by B's statement, B is not the knave, contradiction. So **B is the spy**. And his statement is a lie, so he's a **lying spy** (now that's a good insult!).

Leaving the last case: **C is the knave**.

Comment: Hi @randal'thor  -- I get your point , but am I right in saying that B is a Spy who lies . And Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @pranav I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

B cannot be a knight - they would self identify as a knight.
They also cannot be a knave - they would self identify as anything but a knave. Therefore they are a spy.

TL;DR: anyone identifying themselves as a knave under these circumstances must be a spy.

Edit: B is indeed a spy who lies. By your answer to rand al'thor, they are a knave in all but name.

Comment: Beat me to it by a minute! :-) +1.

Comment: Hi , @frodosylwalker -- I get your point , but am I right in saying that B is a Spy who lies . And Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @pranav B is a Spy who is lying in that particular statement - but see my other comment on your question.

Comment: Hi @frodoskywalker - I have added another comment in the question . Please have a look :)

Comment: The question doesn't make it clear whether a spy is either a persistent liar or a persistent truth-speaker or someone who can sometimes lie and sometimes say the truth.